C# Dynamic class selection at runtime
I have three schemas in my database accordingly CustomerA, CustomerB,Common. The CustomerA, CustomerB schemas will have same set of tables. the reason to have like two separate tables to provide the data privacy b/w customers and each schema will be secured by database users. Will be using individual connection string for each customer. (Same database with different schema with individual connection string )
Assume I have C# class for each schema and both classes will have same set of methods but returns customer specific data. Based on login information I will know which Customer logged in. But I am struck how to call the customer class based on login info dynamically.
namespace FactoryPattern
{

 public interface ICommon
    {
        string GetCustometName();

    }
}

namespace FactoryPattern
{

 class CustomerA : ICommon
    {
        public  string GetCustometName()
        {
            return "i am CustomerA";
        }
    }
}

namespace FactoryPattern
{

 class CustomerB : ICommon
    {
        public string GetCustometName()
        {
            return "i am CustomerB";
        }
    }
}

namespace FactoryPattern
{

public abstract class SomeBase { }


    public sealed class Factory
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> TypeLookup;

        static Factory()
        {
            // You could iterate over additional assemblies if needed
            // the key is assumed to be the name of the class (case insensitive)

            TypeLookup = typeof(Factory).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && typeof(SomeBase).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public SomeBase Create(string name)
        {
            Type t;
            if (TypeLookup.TryGetValue(name, out t))
            {
                return (SomeBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not find type " + name);
        }
    }
}

namespace FactoryPattern
{
    internal class Service
    {
        private Factory factory = new Factory();
        private dynamic _obj;

        public Service(string Account)
        {
            switch (Account)
            {
                case "CustomerB":
                    _obj = factory.Create("CustomerA");
                    break;

                case "CustomerB":
                    _obj = factory.Create("CustomerB");
                    break;
            }
        }

        public string CustomerName()
        {
            return _obj.GetCustometName();
        }
    }
}


 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Service service = new Service("CustomerA");
            service.CustomerName();

        Service1 service = new Service("CustomerB");
            service.CustomerName();
        }
    }


please let me know how to accomplish this architectural related issue.

Typically you wouldn't have a separate table for each customer. You just look up the customer information for the logged in customer based on their ID.

but this is the requirement from dBA for the developers to follow. any ideal how to make this work?

The classes all look the same.  If the data is only changing, you should just change the configuration of the repository service.

You probably need Activator.CreateInstance.

Are you serious, this is a requirement for your database design at work? Are you sure you're not misunderstanding the requirements? That makes no sense because it violates the purpose of relational datasets. IMHO, your dba should be replaced. I would speak to your manager immediately about this design.
